# Position image in a JTextPane (like using setBounds to position JPanel in a JFrame)

Tags: java, swing, layout, awt, jtextpane

I'm new to Java and I would like to know how to position an image within a `JTextPane`. Is it possible? Is there any other methods for positioning an image in a `JLabel`?

Comment: *"..like using setBounds to position JPanel in a JFrame)"*  Don't do that.  It will end with a broken GUI.

Comment: *"Is there any other methods for positioning an image in a `JLabel`?"*  DYM without a `JTextPane`?  Certainly are, and it is easier than positioning an image in a `JTextPane`.  Provide more details of how the image should be positioned, and especially what should happen when the GUI is resized.

Answer (score 1):

The gridBagLayout can be used to position components within a JFrame.

Take a look here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/GridBagLayout.html

I usually use gridLayout,it is less flexible, but easy to use for simple layouts.

Comment: Sorry by "normal", I meant what I am used to using.

Comment: Hmm..  well that edit does clear up the 'normal' part, but I still don't think it is a good answer.  It ignores layout padding and borders for white space, for starters..  But as mentioned, we're really just taking 'shots in the dark' as to which strategy to follow, until the OP clarifies the actual requirement.  `GridBagLayout` is a powerful layout, but not 'the answer to all possible layout requirements'.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a JLabel for the image, call setBounds() for the image and call jTextPaneInstance.add(theImageLabel).Or you can specify any desired LayoutManager for the jTextPaneInstance and just add the label with appropriate constraint.

If you mean something like text flow around the image it's much much more difficult to implement but also possible (depends on EditorKit you use there).